Simpson's paradox: How interpret results?
I am building GLMs to investigate the effect of environmental variables on frog occupancy and abundance (negative binomial). I am having an issue of reversal of estimates which, from what I found on the web, appear to be caused by the Simpson's paradox. The two variables which are affected by it are bio6 (mean minimum temperature of the coldest month) and annual rain. Bio6 has negative estimate when modelled by itself but positive estimate when modelled with other parameters. Annual rain has the same phenomenon but in the opposite direction (it goes from positive to negative estimate).
The top models have bio6+rain+bio8+bio17 (with bio8 being mean temperature of the wettest quarter, which is summer in eastern Australia, and bio17 being precipitation in the driest quarter, which is winter). I am using VIF<10 as filter to avoid multicollinearility but in this case the VIF is even <5 (bio8 is around 4.4 and all others are less than 3). Moreover, I also tried avoid combining bio6 with bio8 and bio17 with annual rain to avoid information on the same phenomenon although they are not highly correlated, however this still occurs. For example, I did a model bio6+bio17 and bio6 still reversed from negative to positive (VIF 2.5). Equally, I did a model bio8+annual rain and annual rain still reversed from positive to negative (VIF 1.38). This occur both when variables are either standardised or not. Now I am in a conundrum because I have to discuss the effect of these variables on frog and I don't know how should I interpret these opposite results. How should I handle this situation?

When interpreting coefficients, it's essential to consider what else is kept constant by inclusion in the model. For example, say we are modeling house prices. You would expect that more rooms will raise the price. You would also think that more area is associated with higher prices. However, the coefficient on the number of rooms will often have a negative sign when you include the area in the model. Why? You can only get more rooms while keeping the area constant by subdividing rooms. But that means a house where the rooms feel claustrophobic. The negative coefficient now makes sense.
I know nothing about frogs, but here is one possible interpretation.
My assumptions:

Frogs like rain - maybe because they lay eggs in water, are less likely to suffer from dehydration or predation, or it improves food availability).
They hate extreme cold and heat since they cannot regulate their temperature.
Rain tends to be cold, especially in chillier months.

Here's my interpretation of the two coefficients and why they flip sign.
The rain coefficient is the effect of more rain on frog abundance, holding winter precipitation fixed. So that extra rain must fall in the summer, spring, or fall. You are holding temp in the wet season (i.e., summer) constant, which means the extra rain must fall in spring and fall, so it is extra cold. So, the temp effect swamps the extra moisture effect and flips the sign. The coefficient is the effect of freezing rain, not just rain.
I interpret the "mean minimum temperature of the coldest month" as the average of the daily lows in July. Here, the coefficient gives the effect of a slightly warmer summer (higher lows). But you are holding the mean temperature of the wettest quarter fixed (which includes summer), so the only way that can happen is if the maxes are lower. Otherwise, the mean temp would creep up. If frogs hate extreme heat, then lower highs could improve abundance.

I second @dimitriy's answer.  Let me elaborate a bit and add a few other notes.
First, Simpson's paradox has come to refer to a situation in which the sign on the relationship between an explanatory and an outcome flips between negative and positive when controlling for a covariate.  Nowadays, 'everyone knows' that controlling for the covariate is the right answer—and it might well be—but the original point Simpson was making is that it matters what question you want to answer.  More specifically, you get two different answers because they are the (potentially correct) answers to two different questions (for more information about this, see my answer to: Examples of Simpson's Paradox being resolved by choosing the aggregate data).
My hunch is that you are interested in the causal effect of bio6 and annual rain on frog abundance, but that you have observational data.  The trouble with doing this is that the variables of interest are often confounded (i.e., correlated with lurking variables that are also correlated with the outcome).  You can nonetheless infer causality with observational data if you control for all of the confounders, in which case the conditional result would be correct.  This is a much larger topic than I can cover here, but importantly, you need to control for exactly the right set of covariates.  If you control for only some confounders, it is possible to have results that are further from the truth than not controlling for any confounders.  It is also possible to control for a variable that is not a confounder (e.g., a mediator) and have that yield results that are further from the truth.  You really have to have exactly the right set of control variables.
Moreover, it is important to determine the set of relevant variables a-priori.  From the write-up of the question, I gather you used a very common and very intuitive modeling strategy in which you tried a variety of models and compared them.  That is a-posteriori (post hoc) variable selection.  The set of variables that you need to control for is the set of all confounders.  You need to determine which variables those are by prior knowledge of which are confounders.  It is possible for a variable to be a confounder and not be significant in your dataset and it is possible for a variable not to be a confounder and be significant in your dataset.  In addition, choosing variables after seeing the results induces bias.  (For what it's worth, I recognize that none of this makes your job any easier.)
Lastly, determining if there is multicollinearity by whether the VIF>10 is reasonable, but it is only a rule of thumb.  1) There is no major difference between 9.9 and 10.1.  2) Multicollinearity is not the same as confounding.  A variable can be a damaging confounder without being collinear.  On the other hand, if you do have multicollinearity, that's kind of a bummer, but it's not the end of the world.  If you need to control for a given variable in order for the conditional estimate of your variable of interest to be correct, you are stuck with that whether it causes multicollinearity or not.  These are just unrelated issues.

Thanks Gung and Dimitryi for your insight. I am a neophyte on statistics, so it’s definitely lot of food for thoughts. Just sharing in case someone else find it useful, I found a package on r called Simpsons and the results show that some clusters of both annual rain and bio6 are affected by sign reversal when combined with some of the other variables in the models. Once that I detect it, should I simply handle it considering the estimate from the model on which they are present alone as the “real effect” (which is also the effect that one would expect for frogs )?

@MarcoLassandro, the point of Demitriy's and my answers is that there is no simple answer to that question.  You have to think about what question you want to answer, why, and what set of variables corresponds to that question.  Then the model that controls for those variables is the one that gives you the answer you seek.  There isn't anything more I can say.

I agree with @gung-ReinstateMonica’s advice.
